# bootstrap navbar: getting search buttons to work

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I've been having a lot of trouble with bootstrap 4.1's navbar - specifically, the search form. I've been using [this documentation link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) to help. I have a search form that looks like pretty standard for bootstrap:

[image: search bar]

I want to allow users to enter some text, and when they click the search button I want them to be redirected to a new link based on the text they entered. Here's the HTML code for this form:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Enter text" aria-label="Search" id="text-form">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="text-search" onclick="searchClick()">Search</button>
</form>
```

And here's the searchClick() function in a javascript file:

```
var searchClick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("text-form").value;
    // alert(text);
    window.location.href = "www.<some-url>" + text;
}
```

I've confirmed I can get the text out of the input box (using that commented out alert), but no matter what I try, it either doesn't redirect me anywhere or redirects me back to the current page. I've tried a lot of different finagling with this code based on other online searches: I've changed the button to an `<a>` with an href field that changes on click (since I can't pre-populate it without the text field value), I've tried adding a return to the searchClick() function, and I've tried messing with classes and changing the type field to things like "reset" or "input" or removing it altogether. I have yet to find a solution, so I wanted to ask here and see if someone who understands bootstrap a lot better than I could give some insight. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, and/or remove the `form` element. Looks like the form is submitting before your javascript has a chance to run.

Comment: Or instead, switch the event handler to on submit and attach it to the `<form>` element.

Comment: Why don't you simply submit the form? (and give the input a name first and the form an action to the desired location/script) There's nothing this function adds to it, so no need for javascript at all.

Comment: No combination of those attempts worked - they all redirected me to the same page on click (and removing `form` stretched the input box all the way to the left). Running `alert(window.location.href)` immediately after setting it to "www.<some-url>" + text also displayed the current url and not the one I wanted to redirect to, so perhaps that's a hint that I'm setting the url wrong (I've also tried setting it with `window.location(<url>)` but got an error trying that).
EDIT: this is in re the first comment, not the following ones.

Comment: add `action="myscriptName.php"` to the form and `name="search"` to the input. Remove the `onClick`. Then your form will be submitted and the value of the input will be sent along as GET parameter of the name "search".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using he [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) method instead of `location.href` property, it is probably also necessary that the text you are trying to attach to the url is passed as a valid querystring. For example: `http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret`

Answer (score 0):

Hi simply add form action and method..you no more need JavaScript.
Example :

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <!-- input field and button -->
</form>
```

Happy coding :)